# Gitlab Package Registry

Tags: gitlab, package, registry

I’m using self-hosted GitLab Community Edition 12.4.2 and I tired to use package registry functionality that I’ve seen in documentation here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/index.html#publish-an-npm-package

to publish my own NPM packages, but I’m having hard time trying to publish them and also I don’t see “package registry” option on menu:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYlCl.jpg)

is package registry available for this version of Gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a self-hosted version of Gitlab, the Package and Docker registries have to be enabled in Gitlab's config files by someone with access to do so.

Enabling Package Registry: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/index.html#enabling-the-packages-feature

Enabling Docker Registry: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html#container-registry-domain-configuration

Comment: There is no "packages" option in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

Comment: What version of Gitlab are you running?